# How to push to github for github to update my server

Tags: git, apache, github

Help will greatly be appreciated, im unsure of what this would be caled so my google searching has been difficult. I have root access on my apache server.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Add a crontab to update your code if you want it to be automatic : crontab -e , then you write the command line to update your server.

Answer (score 1):

What you are likely looking for are GitHub hooks: http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/

Basically with a GitHub hook you can have GitHub post a notification to any URL when something changes in your GitHub repo. Then you can write a bit of code that listens for these notifications and reacts accordingly.

In your case it sounds like "reacting accordingly" would be git pull-ing the latest code, maybe running some deployment scripts, etc.